# Does a data source in Terraform always fetch a list in same order?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

To break it down, I am using the default AWS VPC, and I need to fetch the default subnets and assign it to a public route table or a private route table.  My plan was to use the data source to fetch the subnets and assign the first value in the list to a route table having internet gateway and then all the other values to a route table natgateway. Can anyone suggest me a better approach or does this sound okayish?

Comment: Are you retrieving the subnets with individual `data`, iterated `data`, or one `data`?

Comment: I am using this way 
```data "aws_subnet" "selected" {
  id = var.subnet_id
}```

Comment: That code in your comment retrieves a single subnet, not a list. Your question is about retrieving a list.

Comment: Sorry I meant I am using this ```data "aws_subnet_ids" "example" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}``` This retrives a list

Comment: That list will always be the same order due to Terraform's lexicographical ordering of the `list` type UNLESS another subnet is retrieved in the future and inserted into the list. At that point, the ordering will of course be different. I would recommend using `aws_subnet` with a `map` argument to the `for_each` meta-argument instead to ensure KV pairing (which achieves your end goal according to the question), but we need more details in the question.

Comment: is this documented somewhere, I just need to show this to my client thats why, also does the above approach look okay?

Comment: You could could have one data source for all subnets in the vpc and one filtered by `Tier = "Private"`, then take the difference to get the set that requires the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

The shape of results from a data source are defined entirely by the provider's implementation of that data source, which is in turn influenced by the design of the remote API the data source is interacting with.

A typical provider design convention is to return collections of objects that are *inherently ordered* as a list, but to return collections of objects that don't have any particular order as a set, which is a construct that can contain various items but doesn't imply anything about what order those items are in.

For AWS subnets in particular, the EC2 API doesn't define any specific answer for which subnets are "before" or  "after" other subnets, and so I would expect this data source to return the subnets as a set, and so this isn't a list at all and thus it isn't meaningful to talk about it being "in the same order", because it has no order to be the same as.

Because of that, to meet your requirement you'll need to decide on your own rule for what constitutes the "first" subnet that will contain your internet gateway. For example, you could arbitrarily decide that the subnet with the lexically-earliest subnet ID is the "first" subnet:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "example" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}

locals {
  all_subnet_ids = sort(data.aws_subnet_ids.example.ids)

  first_subnet_id  = local.all_subnet_ids[0]
  other_subnet_ids = setsubtract(local.all_subnet_ids, toset([local.first_subnet_id]))
}
```

In the above, `local.first_subnet_id` will be whichever subnet ID sorted as least by [`sort`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/sort)'s comparison function, which is a lexical sort by unicode characters. `local.other_subnet_ids` is a set of all of the remaining subnet IDs after removing the first one.

Two important things to note here:

- If a new subnet appears later which has a "lower" subnet ID, it will replace the one previously selected as `local.first_subnet_id`, thereby causing Terraform to plan to move your internet gateway into a different subnet. I assume you can't just move an internet gateway between subnets and so that would imply some downtime to destroy the old gateway and create a new one.
- The above doesn't deal with a situation where there are zero subnets in the given VPC, because `local.all_subnet_ids[0]` will fail if there aren't any subnet ids.

You could potentially sort the subnets by some other attribute than their IDs, but this data source alone doesn't seem to provide enough information to do that, so you'd need to combine it with some other lookups to fetch the other attributes of the subnets and do some data structure projection to get it into a suitable shape to sort the set by.